# react-native error Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I don't know where this error happened.
I don't even know why this error occurred.

> error Cannot read property 'split' of undefined.
>
> Metro Bundler process exited with code 1 Error: Metro Bundler process
> exited with code 1
> at ChildProcess. (C:@expo\xdl@57.9.31\src\Project.ts:1861:16)
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)

**And my App.js code**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions'
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { Platform, BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.WEBVIEW_REF = React.createRef();
  }

componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(()=>SplashScreen.hide(), 1000);
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
}

handleBackButton = ()=>{
   this.WEBVIEW_REF.current.goBack();
   return true;
}

onNavigationStateChange(navState) {
  this.setState({
    canGoBack: navState.canGoBack
  });
}
  render() {
    return <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://htomato.netlify.app/' }} style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: is this your entire application?

Comment: try npm cache clean and npm install again.

Comment: and what node version do you use?

Comment: "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-permissions": "~9.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.4.1",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.3.0"